# Which one is more efficient to maintain: JavaScript function references or Boolean + IF conditions?

Tags: javascript, node.js, function, reference

Imagine a task where there is an array of resources which have a `type` property. Based on this `type` there is a need to execute different functions. One way to implement this is via multiple if/else or switch/case conditions.

```
// at run time (run many times)
if (resources[ix].type == 'TYPE_ONE') {
    runFuctionOne();
}
else{
    runFuctionTwo();
}
```

Another way is to maintain one more property like `execute` which would be assigned a function which would satisfy the resource's `type`. Then you wouldn't need if/else conditions and could execute its function directly like:

```
// at assign time (run once)
if (resources[ix].type == 'TYPE_ONE') {
    resources[ix].execute = runFunctionOne;
}
else{
    resources[ix].execute = runFuctionTwo;
}

// then at run time (run many times)
resources[ix].execute();
```

So, **which way would be more efficient? Is there a better way?**

**Edit:** I am more interested in a solution efficient in Node.js environment rather than a Browser environment.

Comment: Does this cause problem?

Comment: What problem do you mean?

Comment: I've created a jsperf http://jsperf.com/javascript-function-references-vs-boolean-if-conditions which shows that in Browsers function references work faster. However a Node.js script reports the very opposite: if/else is 3x faster than function references.

Answer (score 2):

I think a function map will be a better option here.

Define a global map

```
var fns = {
    'TYPE_ONE' : runFunctionOne,
    'TYPE_TWO' : runFunctionTwo
};
```

Then use it

```
var fn = fns[resources[ix].type];
if (typeof fn == 'function') {
    fn()
}
```

Or use [switch](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/switch)

```
var fn;
switch (resources[ix].type) {
    case "TYPE_ONE" :
        fn = runFunctionOne;
        break;
    case '' :
        // execute code block 2
        break;
    default :
        //
}

fn()
```

Comment: Property based function references seem to work slightly faster. See http://jsperf.com/javascript-function-references-vs-boolean-if-conditions.

Comment: @Eye yes If it is upto me in a browser scenario I'll go with the first approach